# Spring boot starter web project : eclipse not able to resolve annotations @RestController and @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, annotations

I started to build spring boot project via following one of the online courses. When completed initial configuration and code, eclipse was not able to resolve @RestController and @RequestMapping annotations even though I have following in my POM file :

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and in dependency section, I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will only be able to resolve these annotations if appropriate jar is in your 'maven dependecies' folder under 'project manager' in eclipse.

How did I troubleshoot this :

Step 1 : 
first we need to know which jar file will be containing these annotation classses. Try to look up google to get hints and still better expand those jar files under 'maven dependecies' folder under 'project manager' in eclipse to see if they have similar package structure that is leading upto specific class.

In my case this time, while I was expanding jar files, 'spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar' failed to expand. Next I went to local .m2 folder to see if this file is properly downloaded.

Surprisingly, I could open the jar file and see the classes.

Step 2 :
I deleted the files under 'm2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.2.4.RELEASE'

Step 3 :
Went back to eclipse > right click project > maven > update project

Step 4 :
select project and also select 'force update snapshot/releases' option and hit 'ok'

above should download files that you deleted again and it should now successfully expand under 'maven dependencies' in project explorer.

Post this my error was resolved as eclipse was able to find the classes.

Comment: So TL;DR is that your local Maven repository was likely corrupt. In that case, deleting and rebuilding is indeed the best option.